# Use of .on method over the .delegate method

Tags: jquery

I gone through the different description provided for the .on() method or .delegate() method. But unable to clarify the actual need of .on() over .delegate().

I just came out with only one difference which of syntax nothing else.

.on() -- function( types, selector, data, fn )
.delegate -- function( selector, types, data, fn )

Any other difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `delegate()` uses `on()`, internally.

The jQuery `delegate()` method's [source code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.delegate):

```
function (selector, types, data, fn) {
    return this.on(types, selector, data, fn);
}
```

So no, other than calling one less function, there is no difference. `delegate()` is there purely to better differentiate between dynamically and statically added event listeners, should you want to.

Comment: delegate is kept for backward compatibility i guess

Comment: From the [`.delegate()`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) API docs: `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.`. So yeah, looks like backwards compatibility to me.

Comment: yup, it is. But which difference made them to deprecate the delegate and introduce the new .on method. they might have used the same.

Comment: Sorry, previously I thought superceeded means deprecated. Is there any major reason which made them to supeceeded the delegate and introduce the new .on method.